# Adding uploaded content into a video to be downloaded

Tags: video, video-processing, video-encoding

I am working on a little project where the client would like to have users upload a picture and it would be worked into an animation much like the elf yourself and some other Jib Jab like animation. The caveat being they would like to let the user download a video of the animation afterwards that they can play anywhere and are fairly set on doing it.

I have been searching, but can not seem to find a service or way to get a server to render the animation with the user's photo to a video file. I am curious if anyone knows a service, a framework/server software package, or possible way to get the server to render a file?

Maybe there is a way for Flash to record the video... though I doubt it has a decent way.

Thanks for any insight you can cast on this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of service, but may be you can take the photos and use mplayer or imagemagik or http://pymedia.org/  to make a video out of them and then send it back to the user.